# Can I declare a class within a function in Python?

Tags: python

How can I define `class Options` inside of my `CheckForJiraIssueRecord` function?

```
def CheckForJiraIssueRecord(object):
    #sys.stdout = open(os.devnull)
    #sys.stderr = open(os.devnull)

    class Options:
        pass
    options = Options()

    options.user = 'user'
    options.password = 'password'

    try:
        com = jira.Commands()
        logger = jira.setupLogging()
        jira_env = {'home':os.environ['HOME']}
        command_cat= "cat"
        server = "http://jira.server.com:8080/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl"
    except Exception, e:
        sys.exit('config error')
    try:
        jira.soap = jira.Client(server)
        jira.start_login(options, jira_env, command_cat, com, logger)
        issue = com.run(command_cat, logger, jira_env, my_args)
    except Exception, e:
        print sys.exit('data error')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    commit_text_verified = verify_commit_text(os.popen('hg tip --template "{desc}"'))
    #commit_text_verified = verify_commit_text(os.popen('hg log -r $1  --template "{desc}"'))
    if (commit_text_verified):
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print >> sys.stderr, ('[obey the rules!]')
        sys.exit(1);
```

Is it possible to declare classes within functions in Python?

Comment: indentation seems to be off...

Comment: Yeah, this is a pretty common pattern when you need the class to be different each time for whatever reason.

Comment: Why do people keep asking "Can I do X?"?  I mean, why can't people just try it?  If it doesn't work, THEN maybe ask "*How* do I do X?" or "What can I do *instead* of X to accomplish my larger goal?".  Especially since this is Python, for crying out loud, one of the easiest languages to just try stuff in.

Comment: maybe i should rephase the question, to what are the implictions if i declare a class within a function. @ John Y, you are right about trying, but i actually wanted to know the implications, and if this is indeed the pythonic way, since python does not seem to be like Perl, where the motto is there are many way to do the same thing, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, however:

1) Each time through the function, `Options` becomes a separate class. Not that you will really be able to write code that exploits (or is broken by) this property, because

2) You can only instantiate the class via the function, unless you explicitly expose it to the global namespace somehow.

3) Assuming that you just need an object with those attributes - i.e. Jira doesn't care about your class interface beyond being able to do `.user` and `.password` - you don't really need to create a custom class at all:

```
from collections import namedtuple
def CheckForJiraIssueRecord(object):
    options = namedtuple('Options', 'user password')('user', 'password')
    # 'user password' are the field names, and ('user', 'password') are the
    # initialization values. This code creates a type similar to what you had
    # before, naming it 'Options' internally, but doesn't bind it to a variable.

    # As you were...
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just correct your indentation and that code should work. You'll be creating a new class each time the function is called.

```
def CheckForJiraIssueRecord(object):
    class Options:
        pass
    options = Options()

    options.user = 'user'
    options.password = 'password'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  Although each time the function is called, you will get a different class.